# Java start multiple threads in a class

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

I am consuming from a certain source (say Kafka) and periodically dumping the collected messages (to, say, S3). My class definition is as follows:

```
public class ConsumeAndDump {
   private List<String> messages;

   public ConsumeAndDump(){
      messages = new ArrayList<>();
      // initialize required resources
   }

   public void consume(){
      // this runs continuously and keeps consuming from the source.
      while(true){
         final String message = ...// consume from Kafka
         messages.add(message);
      }
   }

   public void dump(){
      while(true){
         final String allMessages = String.join("\n", messages);
         messages.clear(); // shown here simply, but i am synchronising this to avoid race conditions
         // dump to destination (file, or S3, or whatever)
         TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(60); // sleep for a minute
      }
   }

   public void run() {
      // This is where I don't know how to proceed.
      // How do I start consume() and dump() as separate threads?
      // Is it even possible in Java?

      // start consume() as thread
      // start dump() as thread
      // wait for those to finish
   }
}
```

I want to have two threads - `consume` and `dump`. `consume` should run continuously whereas `dump` wakes up periodically, dumps the messages, clears the buffer and then goes back to sleep again.

I am having trouble starting `consume()` and `dump()` as threads. Honestly, I don't know how to do that. Can we even run member methods as threads? Or do I have to make separate `Runnable` classes for *consume* and *dump*? If so, how would I share `messages` between those?

Comment: Seems you have the classic producer consumer scenario here, you might find [my answer from a question on software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/337332/250821) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can't really use `ArrayList` for this. ArrayList is not thread-safe. Check out `BlockingQueue` for example. You will have to deal with things like back pressure. Don't use an unbounded queue.

Starting a thread is pretty simple, you can use lambdas for it.

`public void run() {
   new Thread(this::consume).start();
   new Thread(this::produce).start();
}`

Should work, but gives you little to no control over when those processes should end.

Comment: Cool. Was looking for something like this. But, how do I wait for the threads to finish? Because this way, the `run()` method would finish after spawning those two threads, right? Is there a way to make `run` wait? I see that there is no return type for `new Thread()`. As such, I can't catch those threads a objects.

Comment: the threads will never finish since both consume/produce are in a while loop.
You can also just do `Thread t = new Thread(this::consume); t.start(); `

If you expect consume/produce to end, you are better off looking at `ExecutorService` and `Executors` which allow you to submit individual tasks which get scheduled to run on threads.